# Is illegal to sympathise with terrorist organisations?

Tags: criminal-law

Is there a state with rule of law that punish [sympathize](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sympathize)<sup>[1]</sup> with criminal organizations and/or terrorists, and if yes what is the most punitive one?

[1]: With the word "sympathize" is meant to say

1. Define sympathize as "to support and agree with someone or something" as defined in the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sympathize).

Comment: Hi Francisco. Your question is a little unclear to me. What do you mean by "state of right?". I presume by "sympathize with", you mean just making a statement like "I support the Ruritanian independence movement", and not any further action.

Comment: @richardb The state of right is a form of state organization characterized by the equality of all citizens before the law, including those who hold power. Thus, eliminating the despotic character of the state.

Comment: Are you asking if there are places where it is illegal to have certain opinions?

Comment: The edit seems to answer @Joe W's question.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I am still confused as what it means to sympathize with terrorist organizations.

Comment: @JoeW Fair enough, but that wasn't what your previous comment asked.

Comment: Francisco Bytheway, what **exactly** so you mean by "sympathize with criminal organizations and/or terrorists," and in particular what do you mean by "**sympathize**"?

Comment: @DavidSiegel I added my comment after they had edited the post which means it could not answer my question and your most recent comment came before the most recent edit. I would also argue that sympathizing is not remotely close to being the same as assisting or being an accomplice to them.

Comment: @ JoeW I was referring to your firt comment asking about "state of right". I agree that "sympathize" is quite different from "be an accomplice of"

Comment: @DavidSiegel I never said that it was made by someone else. Please check who is the author of the comments before labeling someone else as the author.

Comment: @JoeW, You are correct, my comment was in error. My apologies.

Comment: Where? How do you define "sympathize"? Is it repeating their statements? Is it taking part in their actions? Is it distributing their pamphlets? Donating money?

Comment: @Trish At least one of them.

Comment: @JoeW Certainly in the major German state (Federal republic of Germany) is illegal to have certain opinions, and is considered by a lot of people a state with rule of law. (Note the misnomer that is "rule of law")

Comment: @FranciscoBytheway you are misinformed: it's not forbidden to have certain *opinions* it is illegal to deny certain **facts**.

Comment: If you are going to make claims of it being illegal to have an opinion you need to provide some evidence.

Comment: Asking about the entire world is really too over broad.

Answer (score 1):

No existing government purports to prohibit inwardly holding a particular belief. Some governments prohibit the expression of particular beliefs. For example, in Germany, [Strafgesetzbuch §86a](https://Strafgesetzbuch%2086a) prohibits use of symbols of unconstitutional organizations, which includes the Nazi party. Indonesia has (or had) a law prohibiting the expression of sympathy with the Communist party. The further restriction to a "state of right" does not have any impact at least in the modern world, in that North Korean or Zimbabwean law does not grant special freedoms of expression to the head of state or any other individual. It all comes down to overt actions, and many countries have laws restricting the expression of certain viewpoints.

Comment: "No existing government purports to prohibit inwardly holding a particular belief." While this is true for most of the "civilized world", I'm not at all confident that it is generally true, e.g., in Saudi Arabia, or other states not rooted in typical declarations of human rights.